# dynamic Google Analytics events based on Tag Manager event

Tags: javascript, regex, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am sending events to Google Tag Manger via the dataLayer like so:

```
{"event":"module_email_activate"}
```

And the tags always have a logic to them like {category}*{action}*{label} can I set the Analytics Event is triggered with the category, action and label set dynamically from these parts?
I have already set up the trigger to fire based on regex and I can set the Analytics category action or label to the full text of the tag action btu can I get some modifiers on it or use the matches in the trigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to have three similar structured custom javascript variables that return part of the event name (which is accessible as variable itself)

E.g. for the "module" part:

```
function() {
  var parts = {{Event}}.split('_');
  return parts[0];
}
```

and return `parts[1]` and `parts[2]` for the subsequent bits.

Comment: wait, where can I write my own javascript in google tag manager when firing an analytics event?

Comment: That's a variable of the custom javascript type, which is a anonymous function that must have a return statement. If you then use those variables in you GA tag in the category/action/label fields they will be evaluated at runtime according to the even name.